# How can I sample a 2D texture in a Unity shader without antialiasing?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I'm making a simple 3D game using my own shader, and want to emulate an 8-bit pixel art style. To do this, I need to sample a low-resolution texture without the sampler interpolating between inter-pixel values. Hopefully this will also reduce processing time since it won't need to calculate the interpolation. Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SamplerStates.html ?

Comment: Just a thought; have you considered using the built-in Sprite shader instead of rolling your own? If you combine it with Point rendering mode on the input image, this could have your desired effect, but I'm not sure if that's even your setup!

Comment: I'm using it to keep the poly count low. By using a custom shader I'm able to use two triangles stand in for 32, so I think it's worth the effort. I've actually sorted this out in the texture itself now; turns out I needed to set 'Non-power-of-2' to off as well as setting filter mode to Point; it was upscaling the texture so that it could apply compression.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out there was something I didn't realise about 2D textures. I'd already set its Filter Mode to 'point', which turns off interpolation in the sampling, but I hadn't noticed that there's a box marked 'Non-Power of 2'. What this does is, if your texture has dimensions that aren't a power of 2 (i.e. 1024) it upscales it so that it is. It does this so that it can apply compression to the texture, since compression only works on power-of-2 images in Unity. However, it applies antialiasing to the upscale regardless of Sample Mode, so the interpolation was actually being 'baked in' by the compiler and had nothing to do with the sampler or the shader whatsoever.

Turning this OFF solved the problem; however once I'm happy with my textures I will be expanding them to a power-of-2 size with trailing padding in order to take advantage of it.